# Angular FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected type 'Va', but it was: a custom Pa object

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an Angular application where I'm using AngularFire (`"@angular/fire": "7.4.1`) and Firebase (`"firebase": "9.8.4"`) to query a collection in Firestore with specific constraints:

```js
import { collection, Firestore, onSnapshot, query } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { QueryConstraint, Unsubscribe, where } from 'firebase/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {
    this.listen();
  }

  private listen() {
    const constraints: QueryConstraint[] = [where('lastUpdated', '>=', lastAppStart), where('recommended', '==', true)];

    const ref = query(collection(this.firestore, `all`), ...constraints);

    onSnapshot(ref, async (snapshot) => {
      // ...
    });
  }
}
```

As soon as I'm listening to this query, it breaks with the following error:

```
ERROR: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected type 'Va', but it was: a custom Pa object
```

The error seems to refer to the constraints that I'm passing. As soon as I remove them, the query succeeds without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had mixed imports from AngularFire and Firebase. To fix the issue, it's important to consolidate them and import everything from `@angular/fire` instead:

```js
import { collection, Firestore, onSnapshot, query, QueryConstraint, Unsubscribe, where } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```